# Sparse Matrix format CRS

Tags: sparse-matrices

I am study the format [CRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_row_Storage_.28CRS_or_CSR.29) of an sparse matrix. I have a doubt respect to the pointer row_ptr. What happend if the matrix has a row with all entries zero. Could you help to describe the row_ptr vector in the next case

\begin{bmatrix}
 2 &  0 & 0\\ 
 0 &  0 & 0\\ 
 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The row vector is 
$$1,2,2,3$$
according to http://www.math.tamu.edu/~srobertp/Courses/Math639_2014_Sp/CRSDescription/CRSStuff.pdf.

Based on the reference, if row $i$ contains entirely zeros, you store in row-ptr($i$) the same as in row-ptr($i+1$).

Comment: thanks, but what happens if the last row is all zeros?

Comment: @juaninf: According to that article, if you replace the last $1$ by $0$, I believe the row vector would be $1,3,3,3$ because whenever row(i+1)-row(i)=0, it indicates row(i) is a zero row.